# How to display multiple rows of comma separated values from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help with display of some comma separated enteries from my database.

My main table schema looks like this

```
              |---|----------|-----------|----------------------------|
              |id | tab1     |  tab2     |          tab3              | 
              |---|----------|-----------|----------------------------|
              |1  |  state1  |  A-North  |   constA1,constA2,constA3  |
              |2  |  state2  |  B-South  |   constB1,constB2,constB3  |
              ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Query I'm trying to make work

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE `tab1` = '$tab1'") 
         or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){                  
  $tab3 = explode(",", $row['tab3']);
  echo $tab3."<br>";
}
```

What I want to display from the database

```
               A-North      B-South
               ---------------------                   
               constA1      constB1
               constA2      constB2
               constA3      constB3
```

Error I'm getting  when I run that query is  "Array" . When I run the same code from phpMyAdmin, I get the desired rows (result).

Comment: Your database structure is violationg the first normalisation rule. You better redesign your model to avoid problems like that in the future.

Comment: (Remember to quote both the query string for the database and the output to the browser, e.g. see usage of `htmlentities` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explode gives you the results in an array so you'll want another loop that runs through the $tab3 array printing the result. See the definition from the PHP manual:

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string
>   formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

For example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tab3); $i++) {
    echo $tab3[$i].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

explode will return array using `print_r($tab3)` you can view the items and access it by

```
echo $tab[0];
echo $tab[1];
echo $tab[2];
```

etc.....

Comment: Surely you want to loop through the array? What if there are more than 3 items in there?

Answer (score 0):

`explode ($separator,$string)` returns an array. You need to step through the array to create the table columns.

Also, as you want the data in two columns, create these separately as two separate tables and then include those into a single table as two separate cells

Finally, redesign your database table. You'll thank us in the end

Comment: Thanks for pointing out such a vital information. I was thinking what in a case whereby entries for tab3 are around 100 or 200, does that mean the use will have to keep typing into different boxes? Please how may I redesign the database structure.? 
Thanks

Comment: Move the "tab3" column to a separate table but with each value (i.e., constA1,constA2,constA3 etc) in a separate field with a reference back to the ID value of the main table. Something like `create table tab3 (\`id\` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, \`mainID\` int(10) unsigned not null default 0, \`tab3Value\` varchar(100) not null default '');`.